# Submatrix by colname

Tags: r, submatrix

I have a `matrix` with row and col names and want to reduce it to a `submatrix` certain row / colnames. The specified names are in a string vector of `~20` values, while the matrix has `55.000 rownames` and `805 colnames`. How can I do this efficiently in R?

```
IFNGenes = c('TIMM10','UBE2L6','MX1','IF16','IFI44L','IFIT3','ISG15','OAS1','RSAD2','IFI44','OAS3','DOX58','HERC5','BATF2','LIPA','RSAD2.1')

subMatrix = theMatrix[,IFNGenes]
Error in theMatrix[, IFNGenes] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: How about a small reproducible example?  I guess you can use the `row/column` indexing.

Comment: Code is above, I tried and get an subscript error. Could it be that some of the Genes are not in the colnames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right you are looking for something like this:

```
x <- matrix(1:100, 10)
rownames(x) <- LETTERS[1:10]
colnames(x) <- letters[1:10]
x[c("C", "F", "A"), c("d", "b", "e")]
```

You can also do:

```
x[c("C", "F", "A"), c(4, 2, 5)]
```

If you use an rowname-index (same for colnames), which not exists in the matrix, you get an error:

```
> x[c("C", "F", "XX"), c(4, 2, 5)]
Error in x[c("C", "F", "XX"), c(4, 2, 5)] : subscript out of bounds
```

You can find such indizes as follows:

```
r <- c("C", "F", "XX")
r[which(! r %in% rownames(x))]
```

For your data you have to test:

```
IFNGenes[which(! IFNGenes %in% colnames(theMatrix))]
```

Comment: Yeah, I did not realize you could mix indexing by integer and column / rowname in R.

Comment: Thanks jogo, the which statement was what I was looking for